# options in renderDataTable of server.R were override by the global configuration on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I built a shiny APP. In server.R, I used renderDataTable to show some data frames in this APP. This is the scripts:

```
output$mytable11 = renderDataTable({
     fetchRefByKey(input$publication)
   }, options = list(lengthMenu = c(1, 2, 4, 6), searching = FALSE,
                  pageLength = 1, autoWidth = FALSE))
```

On my local computer (Windows), It worked properly.
[image]

I installed shiny server on the Linux server and configured this shiny APP. The APP runs. But it seems that the options of renderDataTable were override by the global configurations. See the follow figure.
[image]

I had searched a lot on the internet and can't figure out the reason. Can you guys help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that this was caused by the Version of the Shiny packages installed. On my local computer, the version of the Shiny package is 0.10.2.2. On the Linux server, the version is 0.10.2.